# How to only show cities using MapKit in Swift 5

Tags: swift, mapkit

For an app I've implemented Apple MapKit, but when I search I also get local places such as restaurants etc.. How can I filter the results so I only get cities?

I'm using the code below to fill a tableView with autocomplete suggestions using the search query of a UITextField.

```swift
public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController){
    guard let mapView = mapView,
    let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
    
    let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
    request.region = mapView.region
    
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start { response, _ in
        guard let response = response else {
            return
        }
        self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the points of interest with `MKPointOfInterestFilter`

```
let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
request.pointOfInterestFilter = MKPointOfInterestFilter.excludingAll
request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
request.region = mapView.region
```

Comment: Using `MKPointOfInterestFilter` I still get results like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/9L8kmfZ)